# Saving the value from a counter on page refresh - cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, counter, countdown

I'm trying to implement a counter into a website. The purpose of this counter is to represent how much oil is delivered by said company, and to count up by the litre. Code-wise, the logic is to add two every second as a visual representation of the amount of litres, got this bit working.

What I'm trying to do now is save that value so that on refresh, or for when somebody else visits the site, it continues from the current value rather than the original "start" value. I think I may need to use cookies but I've got myself stuck on how to do this, any ideas?

I've included my code for reference, thanks all!

```
var gaugeStart = 320000000;
var gaugePerSecond = 2;
var gaugeInterval = 500;

var gaugeCurrent = 513637030;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gaugeValue').html(commafy(gaugeCurrent));

    var tick = setInterval(function() {
        gaugeCurrent += Math.ceil((gaugeInterval/1000) * gaugePerSecond);

        $('#gaugeValue').html(commafy(gaugeCurrent));
    }, gaugeInterval);
    document.cookie = gaugeCurrent;
});

function commafy( num ) {
    var str = num.toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 5) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
        str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return str.join('.');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93byc54f/

Answer (score 1):

If as you say

> somebody else visits the site,

this is the exact place, where you need to realize, that you must store this information on the server side.

If you need to do this only for a single user, then `localStorage` should be your obvious choice.

Comment: Makes sense now I think about it that way, so would I just send the value to PHP through AJAX per increment?

Comment: I would use the following approach in this case: get the value from the server on load, then increment it with your current solution. On reload, load the value again from the server. So basically the two values can be out of sync, but it does not really matter in this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using cookies will result in every client displaying a different number of litres.
The best way to approach this would be to record the value at a specific time and then provided that we know the increment interval - to calculate the difference since that date.

```
    var gaugeStart = 320000000;
var gaugePerSecond = 2;
var gaugeInterval = 500;

var gaugeCurrent = 513637030;

var now = new Date();
var then = new Date("2016-01-01 00:00:00");

var secondsSince = Math.floor((now - then) / 1000);
var gaugeAmoountSince = secondsSince*4;
gaugeCurrent += gaugeAmoountSince;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gaugeValue').html(commafy(gaugeCurrent));

    var tick = setInterval(function() {
        gaugeCurrent += Math.ceil((gaugeInterval/1000) * gaugePerSecond);

        $('#gaugeValue').html(commafy(gaugeCurrent));
    }, gaugeInterval);
    document.cookie = gaugeCurrent;
});

function commafy( num ) {
    var str = num.toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 5) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
        str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return str.join('.');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mb0pv4ea/

Hope this helps.